Issue with Dynamic and Static Body Parameters in Shopware Flow Builder Webhook
Description / Steps to Reproduce:
I'm experiencing an issue with configuring a webhook action in the Shopware Flow Builder. I've set up a flow to call a third-party API service when the payment status of an order is set to "authorized".
I've tested both dynamic and static body parameters in the POST request:
Dynamic Body Parameters:
{"id": "{{ order.id }}", "customerId": "{{ order.createdById }}", "subtotal": "{{ order.amountNet }}", "total": "{{ order.amountTotal }}"}

Static Body Parameters: Using fixed values for each parameter.
When testing with dynamic parameters, an empty body (body: null) was incorrectly sent to the endpoint. With static parameters, a body was sent, but the API service responded that the parameters were missing. This suggests an issue with the parameter transmission.
Analysis / Checked Points:
Dynamic Parameters Transmission:
The Flow Builder seems to not correctly insert the dynamic values into the POST request body. Instead of the expected JSON data, an empty body (body: null) is sent.
Static Parameters Transmission:
While using static values, a body is sent, but the API service indicates that the parameters are missing. This could be due to a formatting issue or incorrect JSON structure. I've checked the JSON structure and tried various formats to ensure the parameters are correctly named and formatted.
Additionally, we've manually tested the endpoint outside of the Shopware Flow Builder without encountering any errors, so the API service itself is not the issue.
Can anyone help us configuring the webhook action and provide guidance on correctly transmitting dynamic parameters?

